# How can I search for a vertex and create edge in a single query?

Tags: gremlin, titan

I am using gremlin query to search for vertices from a given vertex.

```
v.both("edgeLabel").has("propertykey", "27826345");
```

This query is returning a bunch of vertices. Now I am creating edges from 'v' to all those returned vertices by simple iterator.

> **Now my question is: 
>   
> Is there any process/query style available through which I can search for those vertices and create edges in the
>   same query ?**

I have already tried this query:

```
 v.both('edgeLabel').has('propertykey','27826345').gather(){g.addEdge(v,it,'TEST_LABEL')}
```

But I'm getting error :

> No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.addEdge()

I am currently using Gremlin-Groovy ScriptEngine to execute my query from a Java class.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gremlin 2.3.0, there are three new steps:

```
 linkIn
 linkOut
 linkBoth
```

Please see GremlinDocs (http://gremlindocs.com) for more information on how to use them.

http://gremlindocs.com/#transform/linkboth-in-out

Note that these pipes yield a sideEffect (the edge generated) so you can cap the pipe if you need to get the edge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually I was using Gremlin 2.2.0, probably that's why I over-looked/missed that ..Anyway thank you once again for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide an id to addEdge. Here are the [javadocs](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.3.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Graph.html).

`v.both('edgeLabel').has('propertykey','27826345').gather(){g.addEdge(1,v,it,'TEST_LABEL')}`

Comment: Well from Blueprint API I usually send null for the ID field, so that framework can automatically create it's own ID. But for Gremlin Query I long as I know there's two method one without id, and one with id parameter.
http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/graph-addedge